# Set Image of UIButton Created in Interface Builder, by code

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uibutton

I've got a number of UIButtons set up in Interface Builder (but all linked with appropriate outlet names). These buttons have images set up using the inspector in Interface Builder.

I would however, like to be able to change the images shown in the buttons during a certain event (so for example the user selects an appropriate settings choice and all the buttons change from displaying an image of a frog, to an image of a rabbit).

Is there a straight forward way of doing this? The change must be immediate, not on the next load.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

Would something like, this work for you?

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frog.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I shall endeavour to find out when I'm back at my iMac next :) Thanks for the reply. (Travel a lot so will be nearly a week before I can respond)